# HERE Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, here-api

Just getting started using the sample javascript to simply display a map based on latitude and longitude coordinates. I get a javascript ReferenceError on the very first line!

code snippet:

```
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    

    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'app_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'app_code': 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
        });
        // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('bodydiv'), maptypes.normal.map, {
            zoom: 10, center: { lng: <%=longitude%>, lat: <%=latitude%>}
        });
```

Actual error in browser console:
ReferenceError: H is not defined - happens on var platform=...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including all the JS files mentioned in the example and also the css file
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer

Comment: That certainly helped as the original example didn't have all the includes in it. However, I now get a timeout.   08:46:18.553 Error: [timeout]: Could not fetch meta-info from map tile service @http://1.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.12.4&app_id=lXA1LBkRTiD6gAYsnJEV&app_code=dwXTP9cHq_zH5hVmaQgEjg&output=json
Qj.prototype.dm/<.qd() mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:23
b() mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:10
xj/l<() mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:11
1 mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:23:217

Comment: Figured it out. Original example code was missing many references and calls to ui components. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Hello @KGoddard, How did you resolve your problem exactly? 
I'm getting this error `'H' is not defined  no-undef`.
I'm trying to use Here Maps the routing API with React.JS, and I don't if I need to install any modules.

Comment: There also might be problem with http/https script serving. I had to add `'useHTTPS': true` when initializing the platform object