# Get error "This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair" in heremaps js api

Tags: here-api

I got error "This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair"  ,but credentials are correct. I checked that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE.

Project was created two days ago , so I think that app credentials in whitelisted.

**Update**
here is my code , I just followed the quickstart tutorial

```
platform: any = new H.service.Platform({
 'app_id': '{myId}',
 'app_code': '{myCode}'
});
defaultLayers: any = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();

ngAfterContentInit() {
 this.map = new H.Map(
   document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
   this.defaultLayers.normal.map,
   {
     zoom: 10,
     center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
   });
}
```

and during creating  map I got error

Comment: In order being able to help you, please show us some source code.

Comment: @bkausbk I updated post.

Comment: Please verify if you are using the app id and code for the JS API only.

Answer (score 0):

First just check that app_id and app_code are correct. If app_code is not given then generate app_key and if they are correct just add this line useHTTPS:true. The code given below will generate a non interactive here map.
One of the commments mentioned to use the line (useHTTPS:true) and it worked for me. Refer - [HERE Maps Javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212768/here-maps-javascript-api)

here-map.component.html

`<div #map style="width: 100 vw; height: 100vh"></div>`

here-map.component.ts

```
declare var H:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-here-map1',
  templateUrl: './here-map1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./here-map1.component.css']
})
export class HereMap1Component implements OnInit {

  private platform : any;
  private map: any;

  @ViewChild("map")
  private mapElement : ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
      "app_id": "30AGFBeGk5SbuC4ODTt3E",
      "app_code": "1o21ou0xtPdf7NmvVtoD3Vvke1L0Z0eX56TU5R_FrJg",
      useHTTPS: true
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.map = new H.Map(
      this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      this.platform.createDefaultLayers().normal.map,
      {
        zoom : 10,
        center : { lat : 37, lng: -121}
      }
    )
  }

}
```

I have refered the code from a youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30TNa6LZmFk